# Handling images via REST API

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm trying to create a REST API with django-rest-framework which will be handling a few things, the one being sending and receiving images from the frontend. I found [this](https://dev.to/thomz/uploading-images-to-django-rest-framework-from-forms-in-react-3jhj) article which tries to explain the idea, but it uses class-based approach in its' views.py and ideally I'd like to stick to a function-based one as I've already done some work that way (not including JWT authorization) and I'd prefer it to stay. I have no clue how to make my backend legible of receiving and sending images, could you please try to provide me with some code snippets (or better yet, articles) on how to do so? Thanks in advance!

One thing to mention is that ideally I want to have an endpoint which will handle creating a new object which will come with an image (a plant to be specific) and an endpoint which would handle updating (changing) the object's image.

My models.py:

```
class Plant(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    date_added = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    description = models.TextField()
    img = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True, upload_to=upload_path)
    plant_species = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    last_watered = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    how_often = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    tracked=models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

My views.py:

```
class MyTokenObtainPairSerializer(TokenObtainPairSerializer):
    
    @classmethod
    def get_token(cls, user):
        token = super().get_token(user)
        token['username'] = user.username
        return token

class MyTokenObtainPairView(TokenObtainPairView):
    serializer_class = MyTokenObtainPairSerializer


@api_view(['GET'])
def getRoutes(request):
    routes = [
        '/api/token',
        '/api/token/refresh',
        '/api/plants_data',
        '/api/update_plant/<str:pk>'
    ]
    return Response(routes)

@api_view(['GET'])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def getPlants(request):
    user = request.user
    plants = user.plant_set.all()
    serializer = PlantSerializer(plants, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)

@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def updatePlantTracking(request, pk):
    plant = Plant.objects.get(id=pk)
    serializer = PlantSerializer(instance=plant, data=request.data, partial=True)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=400)
```

Comment: Make sure the encoding of your request should be multipart/form-data.

Comment: Just to confirm, what you want to do is build a restapi, where the front-end can send/receive images via exposed endpoint urls (api). So when a user sends an image it makes a POST request and is sent to the back-end server to be stored in a db. And a user can similarly now make a GET request to the db for image retrieval?

Comment: @user3667054 rather than user making a GET request I want the app to do so (imagine like a showcase gallery with images fetched from db's) but yes, it is something like this

Comment: @JakubSapko so basically like a gallery of all the sent images that the db has received, these are immediately going to be on display for all users?

Comment: @user3667054 as in model - every record is associated with a user that created it. So the user can create a few items and then see those on their site. They can't see others images.

Answer (score 0):

send images or any media files in json string from frontend and make a serializer field to handle the json string.

```
import base64
import uuid
from rest_framework.fields import Field
from rest_framework import serializers

class Base64ContentField(Field):
    """
    For image, send base64 string as json
    """

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        try:
            format, datastr = data.split(';base64,')
            ext = format.split('/')[-1]
            file = ContentFile(base64.b64decode(datastr), name=str(uuid.uuid4())+'.'+ext)
        except:
            raise serializers.ValidationError('Error in decoding base64 data')
        return file

    def to_representation(self, value):
        if not value:
            return None
        return value.url
```

Your PlantSerializer looks like

```
class PlantSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    img = Base64ContentField(required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = Plant
        fields = '__all__'
```

Your post data with img field will look like this

```
{
    "name": "some name",
    "img": "data:image/png;base64,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",
    # ... other fields
}
```

You can convert images to base64 from this [link](https://www.base64-image.de/); In the frontend like reactJS they have packages to convert image to base64 string